# tsung. Fatal config error

Tags: xml, tsung, tsung-recorder

I'v faced with the problem (On debian 8, using tsung 1.5.1.).

The XML config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE tsung SYSTEM "/opt/local/share/tsung/tsung-1.0.dtd">
<tsung loglevel="warning">
<clients>
<client host="localhost" maxusers="400"/>
</clients>
<servers>
<server host="zzz.test.com" port="8180" type="tcp"/>
</servers>
<load>
<arrivalphase phase="1" duration="1" unit="minute">
<users arrivalrate="5" unit="second"/>
</arrivalphase>
</load>
<session name='rec20150703-1430' probability='100'  type='ts_http'>
***here is the recorded through the proxy recorder***
</session>
```

When i'm starting "tsung start" I'm receiving an error:

```
2665- fatal: unexpected_end

Config Error, aborting ! {fatal,

{unexpected_end,

{file,"/root/.tsung/tsung.xml"},

{line,119}, ***my xml consists of the 118 lines***

{col,1}}}
```

anybody faced with similar behavior?

thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose your session in `<sessions/>`  tags, and close the opened `<tsung>` tag at the end like this :

```
<servers>
  <server host="zzz.test.com" port="8180" type="tcp"/>
</servers>
<load>
  <arrivalphase phase="1" duration="1" unit="minute">
    <users arrivalrate="5" unit="second"/>
  </arrivalphase>
</load>
<sessions>
  <session name='rec20150703-1430' probability='100'  type='ts_http'>
     ***here is the recorded through the proxy recorder***
  </session>
</sessions>
</tsung>
```